# Restcord channel->getChannelMessages() gives the wrong return

Tags: php, rest, api, discord

I'm trying to load all messages that have been posted after a specific message ID, but no matter what I input, it returns all messages with the limit provided.

Sample message id: `380407098300956691`

My Code;

```
$pull->channel->getChannelMessages(['channel.id' => 000000000000000000,'before'=> 0,'after'=> 380407098300956691,'around'=> 0,'limit'=> 20])
```

(taken from example page: http://www.restcord.com/Channel/Get%20Channel%20Messages/)

Am I missing something here? (the `000000000000000000` is fake of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to be an issue in the release of Restcord,
Switching to the dev branch solved my issue.